# How can I extract local variables from a stack trace?

Tags: python, pdb, ipdb

Suppose I have a function that raises unexpected exceptions, so I wrap it in ipdb:

```
def boom(x, y):
    try:
        x / y
    except Exception as e:
        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()

def main():
    x = 2
    y = 0
    boom(x, y)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I can move up the stack to find out what values x and y have:

```
$ python crash.py 
> /tmp/crash.py(6)boom()
      5     except Exception as e:
----> 6         import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
      7 

ipdb> u
> /tmp/crash.py(11)main()
     10     y = 0
---> 11     boom(x, y)
     12 

ipdb> p y
0
```

However, when debugging, I want to just put a debugger at the top level:

```
def boom(x, y):
    x / y

def main():
    x = 2
    y = 0
    boom(x, y)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except Exception as e:
        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

I can display the traceback, but I can't view the variables inside the function called:

```
$ python crash.py 
> /tmp/crash.py(14)<module>()
     12         main()
     13     except Exception as e:
---> 14         import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()

ipdb> !import traceback; traceback.print_exc(e)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "crash.py", line 12, in <module>
    main()
  File "crash.py", line 8, in main
    boom(x, y)
  File "crash.py", line 3, in boom
    x / y
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
ipdb> d # I want to see what value x and y had!
*** Newest frame
```

The exception object clearly still has references to the stack when the exception occurred. Can I access `x` and `y` here, even though the stack has unwound?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out that it is possible to extract variables from a traceback object.

To manually extract values:

```
ipdb> !import sys
ipdb> !tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
ipdb> p tb.tb_next.tb_frame.f_locals
{'y': 0, 'x': 2}
```

Even better, you can use an exception to explicitly do post-mortem debugging on that stack:

```
import sys

def boom(x, y):
    x / y

def main():
    x = 2
    y = 0
    boom(x, y)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except Exception as e:
        # Most debuggers allow you to just do .post_mortem()
        # but see https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb/pull/94
        tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
        import ipdb; ipdb.post_mortem(tb)
```

Which gets us straight to the offending code:

```
> /tmp/crash.py(4)boom()
      3 def boom(x, y):
----> 4     x / y
      5 

ipdb> p x
2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the context manager

```
with ipdb.launch_ipdb_on_exception():
    main()
```

It's an easy-to-use wrapper using `ipdb.post_mortem`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need, there are 2 general best practices.

**Just print the variables with minimal code edits**

Have a look at some related packages. For simple usage you might pick [traceback-with-variables](https://pypi.org/project/traceback-with-variables) (`pip install traceback-with-variables`), here is it's postcard

[image]

Or try [tbvaccine](https://pypi.org/project/tbvaccine/), or [better-exceptions](https://pypi.org/project/better-exceptions/), or [any other package](https://pypi.org/search/?q=print%20varaibles%20on%20traceback)

**Programmatically access variables to use them in your code**

Use `inspect` module

```
except ... as ...:
    x = inspect.trace()[-1][0].f_locals['x']
```

**What about debugger?**

Debugger is made for step-by-step execution and breakpoints. Using it to inspect exception reasons is really inconvenient and should be avoided. You can automate your debug session using two mentioned best practices.

Comment: OP is asking about a specific introspection facility. "Just print" doesn't answer the question. The "what about debugger" part is just wrong - this is exactly what post mortem debugging sessions are for; see `pdb.pm()`. The packages you mention actually use the mechanics presented in the accepted answer, but they in no way make it easier to inspect the traceback frames programmatically...